# scala, IntelliJ: stackoverflow exception

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

lang.StackOverflow exception in my code, but I think the issue is with IntelliJ rather than the code issue. So here is the deal (pieces of code):

```
case class Node(data: Int, children: ListBuffer[Node], parents: ListBuffer[Node])

val node1 = Node(thisGuy, ListBuffer[Node](), ListBuffer[Node]())
val node2 = Node(thatGuy, ListBuffer[Node](), ListBuffer[Node](node1))
node1.children.append(node2)

var nodes: mutable.Set[Node] = mutable.Set(node1)
// This is were I am getting stackoverflow exception
nodes.add(node2)
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT** : I suspect this has something to do with toString method. But I am not calling toString method on Node class. Any chance that intellij is calling that method? If so, how to suppress it.

TIA

Comment: Did you write it in REPL or worksheet, didn't you?

Comment: This is a part of fully fledged program, last line is where I get the exception.

Comment: When this exception happens? During code writing, compilation, running, debugging? Please also provide stacktrace for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `node2` as a child of `node1` it creates a circular dependency. 
If you check what scala compiler generated for it:
`scalac -Xprint:typer NodeTest.scala`

the hashCode function is like this:

```
override <synthetic> def hashCode(): Int = {
  <synthetic> var acc: Int = -889275714;
  acc = Statics.this.mix(acc, data);
  acc = Statics.this.mix(acc, Statics.this.anyHash(children));
  acc = Statics.this.mix(acc, Statics.this.anyHash(parents));
  Statics.this.finalizeHash(acc, 3)
};
```

So for node1 to calculate hash code: it needs hash code of node2 (since node2 is a child of node1) and two calculate hash code of node2 it needs hash code of node1 (since node1 is parent of node2)

**Why hash code is important here?**

Because you are using Set which check if an element already exist before putting it in using hash code.

BTW have you noticed that:

```
node1.children.append(node2)
node1
```

Also gives stackoverflow. I am not sure why but looks like toString also has issues with circular dependency.

**EDIT:**
Case classes are generally meant for immutable data structures. So to model what you are trying to achieve you can use class.

```
class Node(val data: Int) {
   var parents : ListBuffer[Node] =  ListBuffer[Node]()
   var children : ListBuffer[Node] =  ListBuffer[Node]()
}
scala> val node1 = new Node(1)
node1: Node = Node@624ea235

scala> val node2 = new Node(2)
node2: Node = Node@12591ac8

scala> node1.children.append(node2)

scala> node2.parents.append(node1)
```

Comment: Using normal class instead of case class as you mentioned. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have infinite recursion in `equals` or `hashCode` methods because of your class hierarchy. Instances of `Node` have cyclic references to their parents and children so one of these methods runs infinitely.

Comment: Yes Sergey Lagutin. I see in the stacktrace that it is infinite recursion of hashCode method, is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: @ArG0NaUt Revise your `Node` class if it's possible to remove `parents` property. If no, override `hashCode` yourself. But I prefer first way.